# Why My ICMP Ping TTL parameter doesn't work in my C code

Tags: c, sockets, ping, icmp

I wrote a C program to implement Traceroute, because I need to get the ip path data efficiently. I hope when I ping an IP I could get all of the Ips between the src and dst IP. So I used TTL to get the Middle IPs, I suppose when I increase TTL one each time, I could get the middle Ips gradually. The code snippet as follows:

```
for(;ttl_val<20;ttl_val++){
  setsockopt(ping_sockfd, SOL_IP, IP_TTL,&ttl_val, sizeof(ttl_val)
}
```

But when I use recvfrom to get the middle Ips, I found it was not correct, the middle Ips always change and they are different with the one I got with linux traceroute command.

The snippet code as follows:

```
struct sockaddr_in r_addr;
addr_len=sizeof(r_addr);
if ( recvfrom(ping_sockfd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&r_addr, &addr_len) <= 0){
    printf("\nPacket receive failed!\n");
}else{
    if(!(pckt.hdr.type ==69 && pckt.hdr.code==0)){
        printf("Error..Packet \n");
    }else{
        //THE MIDDLE IPs were not correct!!!!!!
        printf("=%s\n", inet_ntoa(r_addr.sin_addr));
    }
}
```

For example, my ip is 1.1.1.1, I'm going to ping the dest ip 5.5.5.5, the midway ips are: 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4, i.e these are routes' ips in the path. I hope when I set TTL=1 I can get 2.2.2.2, when I set TTL=2 I can get 3.3.3.3, ect.  I have no idea why my above doesn't work, When I set TTL the code return a random IP and not the real midway IP, because they are different from the Ips I got by linux traceroute command. My whole code as following please:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

// Define the Packet Constants
// ping packet size
#define PING_PKT_S 64

// Automatic port number
#define PORT_NO 0

// Automatic port number
#define PING_SLEEP_RATE 1000000

// Gives the timeout delay for receiving packets
// in seconds
#define RECV_TIMEOUT 1

// Define the Ping Loop
int pingloop=1;


// ping packet structure
struct ping_pkt{
    struct icmphdr hdr;
    char msg[PING_PKT_S-sizeof(struct icmphdr)];
};

// Calculating the Check Sum
unsigned short checksum(void *b, int len){
    unsigned short *buf = b;
    unsigned int sum=0;
    unsigned short result;

    for ( sum = 0; len > 1; len -= 2 )
        sum += *buf++;
    if ( len == 1 )
        sum += *(unsigned char*)buf;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    result = ~sum;
    return result;
}


int atoint(char s[]){
    int i,n=0;
    for(i=0;s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9';i++){
        n=10*n+(s[i]-'0');
    }
    return n;
}


// Interrupt handler
void intHandler(int dummy){
    pingloop=0;
}

// Performs a DNS lookup
char *dns_lookup(char *addr_host, struct sockaddr_in *addr_con){
    printf("\nResolving DNS..\n");
    struct hostent *host_entity;
    char *ip=(char*)malloc(NI_MAXHOST*sizeof(char));
    int i;

    if ((host_entity = gethostbyname(addr_host)) == NULL){
        // No ip found for hostname
        return NULL;
    }

    //filling up address structure
    strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)
                          host_entity->h_addr));

    (*addr_con).sin_family = host_entity->h_addrtype;
    (*addr_con).sin_port = htons (PORT_NO);
    (*addr_con).sin_addr.s_addr  = *(long*)host_entity->h_addr;

    return ip;

}

// Resolves the reverse lookup of the hostname
char* reverse_dns_lookup(char *ip_addr){
    struct sockaddr_in temp_addr;
    socklen_t len;
    char buf[NI_MAXHOST], *ret_buf;

    temp_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    temp_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_addr);
    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    if (getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &temp_addr, len, buf,
                    sizeof(buf), NULL, 0, NI_NAMEREQD)){
        printf("Could not resolve reverse lookup of hostname\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ret_buf = (char*)malloc((strlen(buf) +1)*sizeof(char) );
    strcpy(ret_buf, buf);
    return ret_buf;
}

// make a ping request
void send_ping(int ping_sockfd, struct sockaddr_in *ping_addr,
                char *ping_dom, char *ping_ip, char *rev_host, int ttl_val){

    int msg_count=0, i, addr_len, flag=1,msg_received_count=0;

    struct ping_pkt pckt;

    struct timespec time_start, time_end, tfs, tfe;
    long double rtt_msec=0, total_msec=0;
    struct timeval tv_out;
    tv_out.tv_sec = RECV_TIMEOUT;
    tv_out.tv_usec = 0;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tfs);

    // set socket options at ip to TTL and value to 64,
    // change to what you want by setting ttl_val
    if (setsockopt(ping_sockfd, SOL_IP, IP_TTL,&ttl_val, sizeof(ttl_val)) != 0){
        printf("\nSetting socket options to TTL failed!\n");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("\nSocket set to TTL..\n");
    }

    // setting timeout of recv setting
//    setsockopt(ping_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(const char*)&tv_out, sizeof tv_out);

    // send icmp packet in an infinite loop
    while(pingloop){
        // flag is whether packet was sent or not
        flag=1;

        //filling packet
        bzero(&pckt, sizeof(pckt));

        pckt.hdr.type = ICMP_ECHO;
        pckt.hdr.un.echo.id = getpid();

        for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(pckt.msg)-1; i++ )
            pckt.msg[i] = i+'0';

        pckt.msg[i] = 0;
        pckt.hdr.un.echo.sequence = msg_count++;
        pckt.hdr.checksum = checksum(&pckt, sizeof(pckt));


        usleep(PING_SLEEP_RATE);

        //send packet
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_start);
        if ( sendto(ping_sockfd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt), 0,
           (struct sockaddr*) ping_addr,
            sizeof(*ping_addr)) <= 0){
            printf("\nPacket Sending Failed!\n");
            flag=0;
        }

        struct sockaddr_in r_addr;
        //receive packet
        addr_len=sizeof(r_addr);
//        struct sockaddr_in from;


        if ( recvfrom(ping_sockfd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&r_addr, &addr_len) <= 0 && msg_count>1){
            printf("\nPacket receive failed!\n");
        }else{
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_end);

            double timeElapsed = ((double)(time_end.tv_nsec - time_start.tv_nsec))/1000000.0;
            rtt_msec = (time_end.tv_sec-time_start.tv_sec) * 1000.0+ timeElapsed;

            // if packet was not sent, don't receive
            if(flag){
                if(!(pckt.hdr.type ==69 && pckt.hdr.code==0)){
                    printf("Error..Packet received with ICMP type %d code %d\n", pckt.hdr.type, pckt.hdr.code);
                }else{
                    printf("%d bytes from %s (h: %s) (%s) msg_seq=%d ttl=%d rtt = %Lf ms.\n", PING_PKT_S, ping_dom, rev_host,ping_ip, msg_count,ttl_val, rtt_msec);
                    printf("saddr = %d, %s: %d\n", r_addr.sin_family, inet_ntoa(r_addr.sin_addr), r_addr.sin_port);
                    msg_received_count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tfe);

    double timeElapsed = ((double)(tfe.tv_nsec - tfs.tv_nsec))/1000000.0;

    total_msec = (tfe.tv_sec-tfs.tv_sec)*1000.0 + timeElapsed;

    printf("\n===%s ping statistics===\n", ping_ip);
    printf("\n%d packets sent, %d packets received, %f percent packet loss. Total time: %Lf ms.\n\n", msg_count, msg_received_count, ((msg_count - msg_received_count)/msg_count) * 100.0, total_msec);
}

// Driver Code
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockfd;
    char *ip_addr, *reverse_hostname;
    struct sockaddr_in addr_con;
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr_con);
    char net_buf[NI_MAXHOST];

    if(argc!=3){
        printf("\nFormat %s <address> ttl \n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    ip_addr = dns_lookup(argv[1], &addr_con);
    if(ip_addr==NULL){
        printf("\nDNS lookup failed! Could not resolve hostname!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    reverse_hostname = reverse_dns_lookup(ip_addr);
    printf("\nTrying to connect to '%s' IP: %s\n",argv[1], ip_addr);
    printf("\nReverse Lookup domain: %s",reverse_hostname);

    //socket()
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    if(sockfd<0){
        printf("\nSocket file descriptor not received!!\n");
        return 0;
    }else{
        printf("\nSocket file descriptor %d received\n", sockfd);
    }

    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);//catching interrupt

    int ttl = atoint(argv[2]);
    //send pings continuously
    send_ping(sockfd, &addr_con, reverse_hostname,ip_addr, argv[1],ttl);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile. Please correct the `#include`s.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I removed the # on purpose of StackOverflow treat it Bold font, I will modify the content.

Comment: Still missing the `#include`s

Comment: thank you! now it's the whole code, It compiles and works very well. The file name is myping.c, and I used the following to compile: gcc -Wall -g myping.c   -o myping, And I ran it as:  ./myping www.baidu.com 3, The 3 is ttl, but I found the result is different with the linux command traceroute's result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TTL works well. Use `tcpdump -vn icmp` to observe.

Your code results:

```
$ sudo ./test7 www.baidu.com 3
...
64 bytes from (null) (h: www.baidu.com) (104.193.88.123) msg_seq=25 ttl=3 rtt = 0.196290 ms.
saddr = 2, 162.151.78.85: 0
64 bytes from (null) (h: www.baidu.com) (104.193.88.123) msg_seq=26 ttl=3 rtt = 0.103414 ms.
saddr = 2, 162.151.78.85: 0
^C64 bytes from (null) (h: www.baidu.com) (104.193.88.123) msg_seq=27 ttl=3 rtt = 0.166377 ms.
saddr = 2, 162.151.78.85: 0
```

`traceroute`:

```
$ traceroute -n www.baidu.com
traceroute to www.baidu.com (104.193.88.123), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  *.*.*.*  15.001 ms  15.138 ms  15.121 ms
 2  *.*.*.*  14.828 ms  14.873 ms  15.047 ms
 3  162.151.78.85  14.469 ms  14.941 ms  14.590 ms
...
```

However, on a noisy system (with other ICMP packets flying around) you are receiving also other packets. What you are missing is *filtering* receiving your own ICMP ID and desired ICMP type.

Without filtering, you will receive other undesired data (other ICMP) and you will need to discard (like you did with type 69 and code 0) AND `recvfrom` again. Linux examples of filtering:

```
struct sock_fprog filter;
// set filter with your ID
setsockopt(ping_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, &filter, sizeof filter);

struct icmp_filter filter;
// set filter.data with ICMP types (bitmask)
setsockopt(ping_sockfd, SOL_RAW, ICMP_FILTER, &filter, sizeof filter);
```

Comment: hi Niry, Thank. you very very much!! I understood. But when I used the code you give me, it compiled error, could you please give me more detailed code thanks a lot! The compile error as follows:  error: storage size of ‘filter2’ isn’t known
struct icmp_filter filter2;
‘ICMP_FILTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
setsockopt(ping_sockfd, SOL_RAW, ICMP_FILTER, &filter2, sizeof filter2)

Comment: I have not written a complete example for you, only a direction to look at. You'll need to learn how to set `icmp_filter` and/or `sock_fprog`. You'll need to `#include <linux/icmp.h>` instead of `#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>` for the definitions.

Comment: Also `#include <linux/filter.h>` for `sock_filter` and `sock_fprog` definitions. you'll need `sock_filter` when initializing `sock_fprog`. Unfortunately, there aren't too many examples out there. Best way would be to look at traceroute or ping's actual code :-)